# no viable overloaded '=' error on iOS 11

Tags: realm, ios11, xcode9

I just install Xcode 9 iOS 11 and build my iOS project. I am getting below error on Realm below error.

pod 'Realm', '~> 1.0.0'

[image]

Error:

```
/Pods/Realm/Realm/ObjectStore/results.cpp:489:20: error: no viable overloaded '='
        m_notifier = std::make_shared<_impl::ResultsNotifier>(*this);
```

My project working fine on Xcode 8.3 iOS 10. Issue is facing only Xcode 9 iOS 11.

How can I fix this?

Comment: That is C++ code, not Swift or Objective-C.

Comment: Yes that's right. But it's not supporting on Xcode 9 why?

Comment: Apparently this is already discussed: https://forums.realm.io/t/apple-xcode-9-error-no-viable-overloaded/358.

Comment: Had something similar with my react-native project and had to update the realm version in the package.json file, which seemed to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change your podfile to the latest version of `Realm`:

```
pod 'Realm'
```

This fix is up to version `2.8.1`, so you can type a min version:

```
pod 'Realm', '~> 2.8.1'
```

**A little warning**: If you are using a `pod project` and it internally uses `Realm`, do not forget to update your .podspec file, otherwise your final project will not update and you will continue to get the same error.

Comment: But my application already in AppStore with Realm 1.0.0... Is it work on iOS 11?

Comment: Yes, but you have to recompile your app with the new version of Realm library.